# Amplitude magnification of a transfer function

Tags: functions

I'm given the transfer function below:

$H(s)=\frac{7}{s+3}$

Calculate the amplitude magnification $A(w)$ showing the steps necessary.

I have tried to solve this by doing the following:

$A(\omega)=|H(i\omega)|=|\frac{7}{3+i\omega}|=\frac{|7|}{|3+i\omega|}=\frac{\sqrt{7^2}}{\sqrt{(3+i\omega)^2}}=\frac{7}{\sqrt{9-\omega^2}}$

But I'm not sure that is correct.

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I updated the OP with what I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus of a complex number is obtained by making

$$
|z| = \sqrt{z\cdot\bar z}
$$

where $\bar z$ is the conjugate of $z$

now concerning $H(j\omega)$ we have

$$
A(\omega) = |H(j\omega)| = \sqrt{H(j\omega)H(-j\omega)} = \frac{7}{\sqrt{\omega^2+3^2}}
$$

Comment: That's the link I was missing. Thank you.